# Can someone help me with this Comparison Test problem involving cos?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to determine if this series converges: $$\sum{\frac{cos^2n}{n^2}}$$

So far, I know I'm supposed to use the Comparison Test. And I compare it with the series $\sum{\frac{1}{n^2}}$, which we know converges. But how do I exactly prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $|\cos (x)|≤1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: So, since what you say is true, then cos$^2(n)$ $\leq$ $1$, and the series would be less than or equal to $\sum{\frac{1}{n^2}}$, which would prove that the series converges?

Comment: Exactly, by using the comparison test, which says that if $0≤a_n≤b_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converges then $\sum a_n$ converges.

Comment: oh, I see. I didn't know it was that simple! So if it's cosine or sine, you can just state that it's less than or equal to 1, and finish the proof in a similar manner to this one?

Comment: Yes, the same proof works for sine or cosine, since both of them are bounded by 1. If you had something like say, $\arctan(n)$, you could use the fact that $|\arctan(x)|≤\pi /2$ for all $x$, together with the fact that if $\sum a_n$ converges then $\sum ca_n$ converges for any constant $c$ (in this case we would have $c=\pi/2$ and $a_n=1/n^2$

Comment: Thank you so much. Makes perfect sense to me now!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the fact: $\cos^2(n) \le 1$, which would give you: $$\frac{\cos^2(n)}{n^2} \le \frac{1}{n^2}$$

And the result follows.

Answer (score 2):

Since
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sin(2nx)}{n}$$
is the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave, we have:
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos^2 n}{n^2}=\zeta(2)-\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)\,dx=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2-3\pi+3}{6}}.$$